# Has anybody experience with building a single-page website with silverstripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

Is it possible to build a single-page website with silverstripe? Is it a bad idea - in sight of silverstripe?

How would a template look like to load all articles from several categories and subcategories in silverstripe?

Thanks for any links to tutorials, code-snipets, etc.

Comment: why -1?? haven't u read the use-rules ... you should give a reason, when you downvote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built backbone.js 'apps' with SilverStripe. You load the front end resources as you would any other SS project. I prefer not to use SS template vars to include assets (js/css), as js applications require strict placement guidelines (although it is possible to load everything using the Requirements class).

Check out the [RESTful server docs](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/restfulservice) for examples of usign the SilverStripe CMS to control your data, and use API endpoints to access this data from the front end. In fact, there is no need to have the SS backend and the single page app front end on the same server in this scenario, which is the beauty of REST.

For link handling in single page apps, you can use PushState or listen for hash change events. Either way, the front end JS handles routing, rather than usign SS's Director class.

Please provide more details on what you are trying to do if you'd like more specific help.